# Silverstripe: Add where clause to ImageDataObjectManager

Tags: php, silverstripe

I need to add a where clause to my DataObjectManager.

My existing code looks like this:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Backgrounds', new ImageDataObjectManager( 
         $this->owner, 
         'BackgroundImages', 
         'BackgroundImage', 
));
```

I have tried simply adding it like the below but it doesn't apply the filter and I always end up with all the BackgroundImages returned, not those with the required SubSiteID.

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Backgrounds', new ImageDataObjectManager( 
         $this->owner, 
         'BackgroundImages', 
         'BackgroundImage', 
         "'BackgroundImage.SiteConfigID' = '".$this->owner->SubsiteID."'" 
      ));
```

I have tried putting in an invalid table name in the clause to see if I could get it to error but it doesn't which would lead me to believe that it is being ignored entirely.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'filter' is the 7th parameter of the FileDataObjectManager constructor, not the 4th: (ImageDataObjectManager takes the same arguments)

```
$manager = new FileDataObjectManager(
  $this, // Controller
  'Resources', // Source name
  'Resource', // Source class
  'Attachment', // File name on DataObject
  array(
    'Name' => 'Name', 
    'Description' => 'Description', 
    'Category' => 'Category'
  ), // Headings 
  'getCMSFields_forPopup' // Detail fields (function name or FieldSet object)
  // Filter clause <- **ADD YOUR FILTER HERE**
  // Sort clause
  // Join clause
);
```

see http://doc.silverstripe.org/old/modules:dataobjectmanager

Comment: How do I pass empty parameters is it simply like '','',... etc?

Comment: just pass `null` in this case - see the constructor:  `public function __construct($controller, $name = null, $sourceClass = null, $fileFieldName = null, $fieldList = null, $detailFormFields = null, $sourceFilter = "", $sourceSort = "", $sourceJoin = "")`